# when i change DAO files {org.apache.jasper.JasperException: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast } occur

Tags: java, eclipse, hibernate, jsp, dao

When I change from

```
List<bid> bid = session.createQuery("SELECT  ent FROM bid ent WHERE ent.biderID = :param1  GROUP BY maxBid ")
```

to

```
List<bid> bid = session.createQuery("SELECT  MAX(bidding) FROM bid ent WHERE ent.biderID = :param1  GROUP BY maxBid ")
```

this error occurs:

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to file.bid
```

`file.bid` is entity code

Comment: List<Integer> bid = (List<Integer>) session.createQuery("").list();